# Placing stomp.py consumer/producer inside Flask-Gunicorn python application

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, amazon-mq, stomp.py

I have an existing **flask** application (having a bunch of REST apis) which is  hosted by **Gunicorn**. I also have to send and receive messages from **AmazonMQ** in the same application. I have functions using **stomp.py** to send/receive messages from AmazonMQ, but I am not sure **where to place them**, or how should I use them so as to keep existing flow intact

Comment: I'd recommend a separate process to talk with the message queue. If you like, you can have that separate process then make HTTP requests to your main Flask app so as to keep everything in the same flow.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use Process from multiprocessing python  library, to spin up two different processes? One will handle flask, other will talk to the queue?

Comment: You don't need the multiprocessing library, just start another process, like you'd start your gunicorn application server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for help @AKX,
I resolved the issue by triggering the whole process of messaging (Creation of connection, subscription to channel etc) by a method call from
on_starting(server)
method in gunicorn_config.py